# sum of each element in two lists by ocaml (beginner)

Tags: ocaml

I want to make a list of summation of two lists by recursively.

```
let rec listadd a b
  match a with
 | [] -> b
 | hd::tl -> 
 ( match b with
 | hd2::tl2 -> [hd + hd2]@(list_add tl tl2)
 | [] -> [hd + hd2]@(list_add tl tl2)
 )
```

However, it causes an error.

```
File "test.ml", line 56, characters 17-20:    
Error: Unbound value hd2
Did you mean hd?
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `hd2` is undefined in the case `[] -> [hd + hd2]@(list_add tl tl2)`. I guess you are trying to write something like

```ml
let rec listadd a b =                                                              
  match a with                                                                  
  | [] -> b
  | hd :: tl ->
    (match b with
     | hd2 :: tl2 -> [hd + hd2]@(listadd tl tl2)
     | [] -> a
    )
```

I would also recommend not to use list concatenation, instead appending an element to the head of a list directly:

```ml
let rec listadd a b =                                                             
match a with                                                                  
  | [] -> b
  | hd :: tl ->
    (match b with
     | hd2 :: tl2 -> (hd + hd2) :: (listadd tl tl2)
     | [] -> a
    )
```

While that works, the code can be simplified a lot by using one match only:

```ml
let rec listadd a b =                                                             
match a, b with                                                               
  | [], _ -> b
  | _, [] -> a
  | hd :: tl, hd2 :: tl2 -> (hd + hd2) :: (listadd tl tl2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The name `hd2` is defined by the pattern match in the line above. But the name is only defined for that one pattern match and result. So there's no definition for `hd2` on the line in error. Since this erroneous line matches an empty list, it's not clear what you were intending the code to do.

As a possible hint, it seems to me that the case where the second list is empty should be handled the same as the case where the first list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

And using the List.map2 function :

```
   let listadd l l' = List.map2(fun x y -> x+y) l l';;
```

Comment: This will not work with the lists of different length.

Comment: you are absolutely right - this answer is more to provide a different way to perform the sum.

Comment: Even shorter: `let listadd = List.map2 (+);;`